# How can I select columns from a vectors list?

Tags: r, list, vector, range

I have a list of 322 vectors with this format:

```
...
[[320]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 40  0 32 20  8 25  0 35

[[321]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 35 32 20 13 25 40  0

[[322]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 32 20 48 25 40 35
```

To here is simple, 322 vectors of 15 numbers each one, so i want to make something like this:

```
factlist<-factlist[,1:8]
#Output:
...
[[320]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 40  

[[321]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 

[[322]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

What I want to make is to cut the elements from 8 to 15 leaving the rest but i don't know how to do this with this list format, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, then with `head` get the first 8 elements

```
lapply(factlist, head, n = 8)
```

---

Or using `:`

```
lapply(factlist, function(x) x[1:8])
```

Comment: And even simpler (although perhaps less intuitively): lapply( l, `[`, 1:8 )